# Universal Windows Datatable is missing

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

Did they pull the datatable type from universal windows?  It's supposed to be in System.Data and if I type "System.Data.D", the type DataTable is missing.

If it is indeed gone, I'm going to have fun porting this code over...

Comment: that doesn't seem to exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `DataTable`/`Dataset`/`DataViews` available for windows Universal platform. You can refer more information [Here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/1039)